# Simple Cube Textures Not Displaying

Tags: java, opengl

I am developing a program using lvjgl and lvjgui. There are no problems when trying to display a 2D texture, but when I try to display a 3D cube, not all the texture is displayed. Here is the render code:

```
@Override
public void render(Context context) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   // glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f,0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);


    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

    glEnd();
    if(rotate)
        glRotatef(0.01f,0.0f,0.5f,0.0f);

}
```

Before rendering, the following is performed:

```
public RenderingCallback() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glClearDepth(0.5f);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glRotatef(20f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f);
}
```

The cube itself looks like this:
[Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix8bM.png)

And [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UQP69Mm0XSbrb45kwRnMzA5cviPjAmtX/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, the blue color is not displayed at all, and some textures overlap each other. If you remove one of the sides, a blue one appears. How can I solve this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to have no depth buffer.

Comment: @NicoSchertler How can i make it? Can you give a link to instructions or an example code please?

Comment: How do you create the OpenGL window?

Comment: Does [this post](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=687.0) help you?

Comment: @Rabbid76 https://pastebin.com/JLBsmEBS

Comment: @NicoSchertler No, I do not use Window... in my project

Comment: without proper texcoords, you won't see a properly textured surface...

Comment: @derhass how i can set this property? Can you give a link to instructions or an example code please?

Comment: You already wrote: "There are no problems when trying to display a 2D texture" How did you do that without knwoing about texcoords?

Comment: @derhass as in this example: https://github.com/orange451/LWJGUI/blob/master/src/test/java/lwjgui/OpenGLPaneExample.java
And now i'm this example, but only for 3D

Comment: @derhass: the OP clearly uses the word "texture" incorrectly. What they mean is that they don't see some of the faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tnx all for help, and @ybungalobill for solution. 
I'm add

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

in `render(Context context)` void and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

You are missing depth buffer. In LWJGL initialization, provide a size for depth buffer before calling `glfwCreateWindow`:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 16);
```

You should also clear the depth to 1.0 instead of 0.5:

```
glClearDepth(1.0f);
```

Comment: @DmitryTriangle: I bet your `RenderingCallback` is never called. Try changing the `glClearColor` and check this hypothesis.

Comment: @ybungalobill https://pastebin.com/JLBsmEBS in line 34 i call his. And i see result of `glRotatef`

Comment: @DmitryTriangle: move you depth and clear setup into `render()`.

Comment: @ybungalobill https://github.com/Aryesia/OpenGLTestProject - full project